# how to make edit text view content scrollable in android

Tags: android

### Unable to add scrolling here in Edittext

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/et_note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:gravity="top|start"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:padding="@dimen/padding_tiny"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Try to add this in edittext android:scrollbars="vertical"

Answer (score 1):

```
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:editable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:focusable="true"
```

After using all those properties in `<EditText>`, I got success.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_note"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_tiny"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
</EditText>
```

As @ajantha said in a comment,        `android:scrollbars="vertical"` should work perfectly.